# Cannot import name six Django-CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms, six-python

Am Using django 1.3 and django-cms 2.2 and when i run i get an error as follows:

> django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'cms_tags' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading cms.templatetags.cms_tags: cannot import name six

Comment: If you are just starting out, use the latest django version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have Django version >=1.4.5. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this same error, the `six` import error is being caused by an incompatible version of `django-mptt`. This should do the trick:

```
$ pip install django-mptt==0.5.2
```